# HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["cxml-urlencoded"] has no data

Tags: c#

We have aspx c# based Punchout application that successfully opens vendor page (Amazon in this case) with proper credentials. I can pick items and submit for approval. Amazon then POST the request back to our application with cXml data that we need for PR processing. However, when we try to read that data using
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["cxml-urlencoded"] (in c#)
it is not there. All I see is the request header (using Request.ServerVariables["ALL_RAW"]). Using F12 (in IE), I can see that there is a request header and request body with the data that we need but the body is not coming through.
If we use other vendors (Home Office for example) then there is no issue. Everything works fine.
One difference I have noticed is that with Amazon request POST, our application redirects it to the login page where it gets credentialed using the data in the cookie object and then it goes to our PR area where it fails due to missing data values. This login redirection doesn't happen with other vendors.
Any suggestion on why Form["cxml-urlencoded"] might be null or why Amazon POST request is getting redirected but not others? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We found the reason for the redirect. One of our cookies getting dropped when Amazon posts its request back to our application. Not sure why it is disappearing though. So we made some changes to our side to handle this missing cookie. Not a perfect solution but will get us going for now.